# Redirecting Output

Tags: c, linux, bash, file-io

I was playing around with redirection when I noticed something I don't understand.

I have a basic multi-client server program which writes a message to the standard output when a user connects or disconnects.

If I run and close 2 clients in other terminals, the output will be something like this:

```
Waiting for connections....
A user connected
A user connected
A user disconnected
A user disconnected
```

If I redirect the output to a file via

```
./Server >logfile.txt
```

When I open the logfile I see something like this:

```
Waiting for connections....
A user connected
A user disconnected
Waiting for connections....
A user connected
A user disconnected
```

My question is: how can I get same outputs?

Comment: This makes no sense - the output should be the same. Try piping the output thru tee, which will show it on the console and write it to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that your server program has code rather like this:

```
printf("Waiting for connections...\n");
while ((handle = new_connection()) != 0)
{
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "...");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("A user connected\n");
        manage_connection(handle);
        printf("A user disconnected\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

When run with the output going to the terminal, the output is line buffered, so the `Waiting` message appears immediately.

When run with the output going to a file, the output is fully buffered; the data is not sent to file until the buffer fills, or an explicit `fflush()` occurs, or an `fclose()`, or the process exits normally.  That means that the child process has the `Waiting` message in its buffer, and a copy of the message will be printed for each child process.

The only way to fix it is to modify the server program. You can use `fflush()` after printing the 'Waiting' message (and before the loop), or you can set the output buffering to `_IOLBF` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, i will try this since its the only thing that makes sense.Thank a lot